# How to supply a weight matrix to focal_hpc in R

Tags: raster, r, spatial-statistics, focal-statistics

I'm using the function `focal_hpc` from `spatial.tools` in R to compute for each cell of a raster the average value (`mean` function) around windows of a specific size (3 cells x 3 cells).

I used to perform this analysis using the similar function focal, which is however slower than `focal_hpc` when using large raster files.

The advantage of focal is that the user can specify a matrix of weights. However, `focal_hpc` does not seem to provide this option.

I have been trying to use a custom function, such as:

```
f_mean = function(x,weight_pix){
  x[is.na(x)]<-0
  weighted.mean(x,weight_pix)
}
```

However, I keep getting this error, which I do not really understand:

```
Error in weight_pix * x : non-conformable arrays
```

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: The help indicates that the `rasterEngine` function should be used in leu of `focal_hpc`. That aside, help states " the input can be passed to the function as an array". Your current function is operating on a vector. You may be able to simply coerce the `x` matrix/array to a vector as the first step in your function. I commonly do this in `raster::focal` functions.

Answer (score 0):

to apply a focal or moving window to your raster cells I can suggest two option, but I don't know if that's what you asked, and which one is faster ^^

The first one from the package raster :

```
f_mean = focal(x, w=matrix(1,3,3), fun = mean) #x (your raster) ; w= here a matrix 3*3 with value of 1
```

Second one from package mmand, that I prefere

```
library(mmand)
Kernel = shapeKernel(c(3,3), type="box") # you can set the size of the window (or kernel), and shape of it!
tmp = meanFilter(as.matrix(r), Kernel) #you can use medianfilter as well
f_mean = setValues(r,tmp)
```

I like the package mmand, there are some other options, like gaussian filters, or morphological operation (opening, closing, etc)